# Linked Combobox in EXTJS4

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.1

I'm trying to create a linked combobox using EXTjs4, Im thinking of using static array data sources. I looked at the examples in sencha website but i couldn't find any. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `linked combobox` and what is the question exactly?

Comment: Say i have 2 combo boxes. If i select item 1 in Combo box 1 then item1 of combo box2 should be selected. (or the corresponding item).

Comment: Well, you can either use a store directly (like in the [doc's example usage](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox), or you can provide a combo with a [two-dimensional array](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-store). Is there anything else you need help with?

Comment: I'm aware of the 2D array, But i'm looking for an example using listeners for populating the 2nd combo box based on the selection of first combo box

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like that in the past. I had two combo boxes - one showing employees (valueField: EmployeeID) and the other showing managers (valueField: EmployeeID). When the user selects an employee then the other combo box automatically showed that employee's manager. This is what I used:

```
var EmployeesComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    listeners:{
         'select': function(cbo, records) {
              // set the value of the other combo box to the selected employee ID
              Ext.getCmp('id_of_2nd_combo_box').setValue(records[0].data.EmployeeID);
          }
    }
});
```